Run action after viewChild render
I have the following template:
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DynamicFormComponent, NgForOf, NgIf, NgSwitch, NgSwitchCase, NgTemplateOutlet],
  template: `
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="method">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="file">
      <ng-container *ngIf="!isFileUploaded; else form">
        ...some html...
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="manual">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="form"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

<ng-template #form>
  <app-dynamic-form></app-dynamic-form>
</ng-template>
`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent, { static: false })
  public form!: DynamicFormComponent;

  private createForm(): void {
    // method to run after DynamicFormComponent render...
    const fields: any[] = this.createFields();
    this.form.setFields(fields);
  }

  createFields(): any[] {
    return [/*fields...*/]
  }
}

I want to initialize a variable inside <app-dynamic-form> using its internal setFields() method.
export class DynamicFormComponent {
  public fields: any[];

  public setFields(val: any[]): void {
    if (val) {
      this.fields = val;
    }
  }
}

The problem occurs when this component is rendered later via ng-template than when the parent is initialized. I tried doing it in ngAfterViewInit() but to no avail, I also tried emitting the event in ngOnInit() but that doesn't work either.

can you more clarify your question?
What do you want, what is your expected result?

@DaksheshBaldaniya I want to use createForm() method but it has to be used after <app-dynamic-form> appearance in DOM. Where should I use it to be sure that the component has already been rendered and I won't get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setFields') ?
If this tag appeared somewhere outside ngIf and ngTemplate, I use the ngOnInit() method and the problem is solved, but here I need to display it conditionally.

You can emit event on init from DynamicFormComponent
export class DynamicFormComponent {
  public fields: any[];

  @Output() onInit: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onInit.emit(true);
  }

  public setFields(val: any[]): void {
    if (val) {
      this.fields = val;
    }
  }
}

Now bind create form method with 
<app-dynamic-form (onInit)="createForm()" ></app-dynamic-form>


Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this doesnt work, i get same error
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setFields').
Also i checked this.form and its undefined

There are two ways of doing this:

use output in your app-dynamic-form component. There are two things to keep in mind in this solution:


you should trigger event emitter asynchronously from child because otherwise you might get error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. It happens because Angular does uni-directional change detection flow from parent to child and if you do sync emit during this change detection up then state might change in parent (depends on what you gonna do in handler) but since angular has already checked parent and you do this you might catch inconsistencies in rerendering.
to make your ViewChild be caught by parent you should either do an async output as in option above (then parent gonna catch event when viewchild is defined), or use output handler with hook like ngAfterViewChecked so that viewchild is caught.

actually using async output resolves both things:
app-dynamic-form:
@Output() init = new EventEmitter<void>(true); // true defines that eventemitter should trigger asynchronously in the next event loop tick

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.init.emit();
}

after than you should be able to catch init in parent and have it defined in ViewChild property.

Other way is a bit tricky but just to let you know another option, there is no need to add outputs and so on but need to handle changes of viewchild via hook ngAfterViewChecked:
parent:
@ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent, { static: false })
  public form!: DynamicFormComponent;
private childInited = false;

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  if(!this.childInited && this.form) {    
    this.childInited = true; // toggle not to get triggered by next change detection cycle
    setTimeout(() => this.onDynamicFormInited());
  }
  else if(!this.form) { // handle the case when there was form but then hid by ngIf 
    this.childInited = false;
  }
}

private onDynamicFormInited(): void {
  ...
}

Note: use setTimeout if you do state(things that are used in template) changes is added not to catch that exception of expression changed during change detection
And since your component is OnPush, need to add markForCheck there then, otherwise setTimeout state changes will not be rerendered

Thanks for your answer.
First way: What does it mi "catch init in parent"? Do you mean i should use this output in template and react to its emit with my action?
Second way: that worked but witch one big problem - infinite loop of createForm() in setTimeout()

first way is the same as in another answer but you should emit asynchronously, either you should do new EventEmitter(true) to make it async, or manually wrap init.emit() in setTimeout, about infinite loop: you should keep in mind this not to make it. that's why ngAfterViewChecked has these handlings to execute it only once when viewchild component is detected (toggle boolean). btw I forgot to toggle it. Just updated my answer
